# Column comparison using awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I would like to compare the first column of file1 with the second column of file2 and only if they match it should display any matching lines in file2 only as the output. The columns are separated by `|`.

`file1`:

```
syfar03040k16.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040m02.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040m04.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040n11.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040n01.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040n02.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040n03.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040n05.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040n07.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o11.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o01.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o02.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o03.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o13.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o05.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o04.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
syfar03040o16.audc1.oraclecloud.com |
```

`file2`:

```
   | LDAP                 | syfar03040o11.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | OIM                  | syfar03040o01.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | AUTHOHS              | syfar03040o02.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | APPOHS               | syfar03040o03.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | BI                   | syfar03040o04.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | ADMIN                | syfar03040o05.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | PRIMARY              | syfar03040o06.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | SECONDARY            | syfar03040o07.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | APPOHS_HA1           | syfar03040o13.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | PRIMARY_HA1          | syfar03040o16.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | SECONDARY_HA1        | syfar03040o17.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | OSN                  | syfar03040o09.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
```

`File3`:

```
   | LDAP                 | syfar03040o11.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | OIM                  | syfar03040o01.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | AUTHOHS              | syfar03040o02.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | APPOHS               | syfar03040o03.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | BI                   | syfar03040o04.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | ADMIN                | syfar03040o05.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | APPOHS_HA1           | syfar03040o13.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
   | PRIMARY_HA1          | syfar03040o16.audc1.oraclecloud.com               |
```

Comment: I simplified your data to make your question more understandable. If I seriously changed the meaning, [edit] it yourself and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        file1[$1] = 1;
        next;
    }
    $4 in file1 {
        print $0;
    }
' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank You. But the code does not seem to work with my original files.  There is no output displayed. I initially tried

awk  -F"|"   'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next} a[$4] {print $0}'  file1 file2

but with this it just display the entire file 2 which is not my requirement

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

For reference again, Here are my original files-

Comment: I tried this code and it worked


 awk '
>     FNR == NR {
>         a[ $1 ] = 1;
>         next;
>     }
>     FNR < NR {
>         if (  ($4 in a) ) {
>             print $0;
>         }
>     }
> ' file1 file2
              

..........

Comment: @nehadhawan Yes I see, there was a mistake with the file delimiters in my answer. I updated it; also, the `FNR < NR` test in your code can be left away. `FNR` is the current record number in the current file and is reset to 0 when the next file is read, while `NR` is the total number of records. So after the first file has been read, `FNR < NR` will always be true.